# Desnormalize a table with python

Tags: python, pandas, pivot, pivot-table

I'm confused when i have to desnormalize a table with pandas For example, i have this table:

[image]

And I would like to desnormalize and receive something like that:

[image]

I'd appreciate your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```py
df["tmp"] = df.groupby("Idn")["Idn"].transform("cumcount") + 1

x = df.pivot(index="Idn", columns="tmp")
x.columns = [f"{name}{c}" for name, c in x.columns]
print(x.reset_index())
```

Prints:

```
    Idn  test_m1  test_m2  test_m3       date1       date2       date3  test_p1  test_p2  test_p3
0  4393        1        7        4  2010-12-19  2019-05-24  2012-04-16        8        2       10
```

Comment: I appreciate your help
and if i have two different "idn" that code would work at the same way, right?

Comment: @WorkAll Yes, it should work with more `idn`s

Comment: Your help is pretty appreciated, you saved my day.